# Bash Script exec file descriptor returning "not found"

Tags: bash, exec

I want to set all debugging output to a log file. So I checked [command line - bash: set -x logs to file | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811439/bash-set-x-logs-to-file) and followed the instructions.

test-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 5 >/var/log/test.log
export BASH_XTRACEFD=5
main(){
set -x
echo hello
set +x
}
main
```

run:

```
./test-script
```

returns:

```
exec: 5: not found
```

The manual shows you can do this as well, so why is the above not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error gets you halfway there:

> exec: 5: not found

`exec` tried to execute a command called `5`, and didn't find it.

The [syntax for redirecting a file descriptor](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) calls for *no space* between the file descriptor number and the redirection operator, like so:

```
exec 5> /var/log/test.log
```

Answer (score 5):

There should be no space between `5` and `>` on the `exec` line.

With the space, the script tries to execute a command called `5`, which is why you get "not found".

Without the space, you attach file descriptor 5 to the given file name for output.

Additionally, there is no need to export the variable `BASH_XTRACEFD`, it's enough to just set it:

```
#!/bin/bash 

exec 5>test.log   

BASH_XTRACEFD=5

main () {           
    set -x        
    echo hello    
    set +x        
}

main
```